# Animate AutoLayout constraints with different animation curves simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout, caanimation

How to animate AutoLayout constraints with different animation curves simultaneously?

For example, animate `widthAnchor` and `heightAnchor` with linear curve, but animate `centerXAnchor` and `centerYAnchor` (on the same view) with spring animation. *Both animations need to be performed simultaneously.*

All I know is how to animate everyone at once (calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()` inside `UIView.animate`), but how to animate them separately?

Answer (score 0):

you have to perform operation like below:-

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    //perform animation of height
}, completion: { _ in

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
       //perform animation of width
    }, completion: nil)
})
```

and if you want add some animation option then use below code:--

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions."Set your Animationoption", animations: {
    //perform animation of height
}, completion: { _ in

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions."Set your Animationoption", animations: {
       //perform animation of width
    }, completion: nil)
})
```

Both to together:-

```
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions."Set your Animationoption", animations: {
       //perform animation of width
    }, completion: nil)

 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions."Set your Animationoption", animations: {
       //perform animation of height
    }, completion: nil)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if I have to animate both simultaneously with different curves?

Comment: @V D Purohit AFAIK, your code animates `width` and `height` in sequence right? how to animate both of them together?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create `CABasicAnimation`s where the `fromValue` is set to the current value of each view, and call `layoutIfNeeded()` after that without an animation block. The latter will change the frames of the views. If you add the animations after the layout step the modifications should be animated.

This could look like this

```
let animation1 = CABasicAnimation()
let animation2 = CABasicAnimation()

animation1.fromValue = view1.center
animation1... // Set further properties to configure the animation
animation2.fromValue = ... // Same with second view
// and so on
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
view1.layer.add(animation1, forKey: "center")
view2.layer.add(animation2, forKey: ...)
```

I haven't tried it, but I'd be happy to hear whether it works or not.